# Incluir Vários Arquivos Custom Post Type com Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: plugin-wordpress, custom-post-types, wordpress

Bom dia, estou precisando de incluir vários arquivos em um Post Type, estou usando o ACF (Advanced Custom Fields), para a criação dos campos personalizados.

É possível fazer isso sem a criar um outro post type apenas para incluir esses arquivos e relacionar no Post Type que estou criando?

Adicionei o campo de conteúdo > arquivo no ACF, mas esse campo só está me permitindo incluir 1 arquivo.

[ ]'s Robison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infelizmente não é possível com o plugin básico do ACF. Você pode usar algum plugin similar ao ACF ou use o [add-on Repeater](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/), do próprio ACF.

[advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/)